# Non-Git Github?

Tags: git

This is probably a really weird question... but is there a non-git Github?

I want a place to post my projects and share my code (like Github) but I don't want to have to works with versions, commits, etc. I don't like having to create a link between my folder and my git repo and then push the changes etc. In addition, I don't want to have to have a local copy to create or add files; I can edit existing files in Github, but to create or add files, I have to do it locally and then commit and push.

I'm not sure if this is the best site to ask on, but I figured someone might have the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you want to post code online without using version control? Sure, just find whatever hosting service you want. Post a zip file containing your source code. That's how people did it for years before sites like Sourceforge.

Comment: Or just use a standard FTP hosting.

Comment: But I like that I can create repositories for each project and that peers can view the code without having to download the entire project. I have a VPS and a Shared Host, so uploading projects is simple enough, I just like the community aspect of it.

Comment: Okay, don't make a zip file. Just put each source file online in whatever directory structure you like. It's messy, inconvenient, and hard to keep up to date, which is why we have sites like Github today.

Comment: I agree that Github isn't very appealing to new users, I'll +1 just for the sake of expecting an answer to this as well.

Comment: @GregHewgill if I upload the PHP file, it won't show the code, it will execute it. If I put it in a .txt file, it won't have syntax highlighting. If I put it in a .txt or .html (with syntax highlighting), it means that every time I change the code, I have to open the .html file, copy the code in, upload it to the server, etc... It might not sound like a lot, but if I change twenty files five times, it means one hundred of those which gets tiresome.

Comment: dropbox? https://www.dropbox.com/ : one of my rules - if your code is not in version control it doesn't exist

Comment: @house9, the version control isn't the bad part. Its the pulls, commits, and pushes that get to me. I'd be fine with a version control system if it did it automatically every time I changed something...

Comment: try dropbox then, you can share a folder (repo) with one or more people right from your hard drive without uploading anywhere; ideally you would get to the point where working with git is part of your natural development practices add, commit often, push/pull when sharing

Comment: Sounds like you want Google Docs with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/create/) yet?

Still, I'd encourage you to try some more Git. The social network aspect built into GitHub is worth the learning effort.

Comment: I just made an account but the only way to add files to a project seems to be Git, SVN, or Mercurial. Is there another way (FTP)?

Comment: No, SourceForge is “like GitHub” in the way that it hosts source files based on a version control system. I doubt you’ll find a project host that won’t do that.

Comment: Not really the "non-Git" solution I was looking for, but after looking at SourceForge I realized how much Github was and I ended up using the Github for Mac to make the process easier.